# Is there conditional try statement in Kotlin like in Swift?

Tags: android, kotlin, exception

I found it extremely annoying to write ugly try/catch statements in Kotlin each time when I want to do something simple like:

```
val el = collection.filter{condition}.first
el?.field // this is not going to work since 'first' can throw an exception
    or
val l = someString.toLong() // This can throw NumberFormatException
```

There is a nice try? statement in Swift:

```
let el = try? expression
el?.field // this will work like a charm
```

Is there anything like this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val el = collection.firstOrNull{condition}
el?.field
```

You always can create your own function

```
inline fun <R> expressionOrNull(block: () -> R): R? {
    return try {
        block()
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        null
    }
}

val el = expressionOrNull { expression }
el?.field
```

or you can use standard library

```
val el = runCatching { expression }.getOrNull()
el?.field
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really neat. What about the second one with conversion to Long?

Comment: `someString.toLongOrNull()` ?

Comment: Yeah, I've typed too soon. Thanks. Still, I think try? is more universal since it can handle any excpetions

Comment: I'll probably use that function approach. Thanks again.

Comment: wouldn't this be a suitable case to use an extension method as well ?

Answer (score 2):

See [IR42's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67037340/115145) for built-in solutions. However, it's fairly easy to set up your own, if you do not like those:

```kotlin
fun <T> tryOrNull(block: () -> T): T? {
  return try {
    block()
  } catch (t: Throwable) {
    null
  }
}

fun main() {
  val foo = tryOrNull { listOf(1).first() }
  val bar = tryOrNull { emptyList<Int>().first() }
  
  println("foo: $foo, bar: $bar")
}
```

The output is `foo: 1, bar: null`, as `emptyList<Int>().first()` results in an exception, so `tryOrNull()` evaluates to `null`.

Personally, I'm not a fan. Exceptions are hugely useful bits of information that your approach expressly ignores. But, it's possible to do.